# Нужна помощь с `PySide2`!

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, qt-designer, pyside2

После компиляции из **`.ui`** в **`.py`** открываю уже `.py` файл в `sublime text` и там нету части кода которая мне нужна. Пытался вводить в ручную:

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from main import Ui_Dialog

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
ui = Ui_Dialog()
ui.setupUi(Dialog)
Dialog.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Но не работало даже пробовал двумя методами из двух разных видео на ютубе, где во втором случае нужно вместо `dialog` ставить `Form`. Что мне делать с этим? Помогите!

---

Часть кода которого нету:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
  Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
  ui = Ui_Dialog()
  ui.setupUi(Dialog)
  Dialog.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Компилирую командой через консоль:

```
pyside2-uic "D:\python projects\.ui Files\gg.ui" -o "D:\python projects\.py Files\main.py"
```

**gg.ui**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>381</width>
    <height>533</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">QWidget {
    background-color: #303030;
}

QPushButton {
    color: #08c7ba;
    background-color: #7f1c1c;
    width: 90px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 900;
    border-style: groove;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: #0f0e0e;
}
QPushButton:hover {
    border-color: #03cc00;
    border-style: outset;
}
QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: #25b522;
    border-color: #196318;
    border-style: inset;
}</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="gridLayoutWidget">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>190</y>
     <width>381</width>
     <height>351</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="3" column="2">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_9">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Nothing</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="1">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
      <property name="text">
       <string>BuildingTypes</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>PvpBoosts</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_4">
      <property name="enabled">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
      <property name="cursor">
       <cursorShape>ArrowCursor</cursorShape>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>ClicksImitation</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="2">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_6">
      <property name="text">
       <string>AutoThings</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="3" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_8">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Nothing</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="5" column="1">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_10">
      <property name="text">
       <string>CloseProgramm</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="2">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Nothing</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="3" column="1">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_7">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Nothing</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="1">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_5">
      <property name="text">
       <string>SpinBots</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>50</y>
     <width>381</width>
     <height>151</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">color: #ba36cf;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: 900;
</string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string/>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>381</width>
     <height>41</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background-color: #4a4a4a;
color: #e84848;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 900;
border: outset;</string>
   </property>
   <property name="html">
    <string>&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd&quot;&gt;
&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;meta name=&quot;qrichtext&quot; content=&quot;1&quot; /&gt;&lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;
p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
&lt;/style&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body style=&quot; font-family:'MS Shell Dlg 2'; font-size:16px; font-weight:792; font-style:normal;&quot;&gt;
&lt;p style=&quot;-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: А где у вас импорт PySide2?

Comment: Ой извините забыл добавить в вопрос, сейчас добавлю)

Comment: Покажите полный код как вы делаете

Comment: Сейчас исправлю всё на то как я делаю подождите немного пожалуйста

Comment: Покажите ваш файл `.ui`. Объясните лучше какой части кода нету? Покажите какой строкой вы компилируете `.u`i в .`.py`.

Comment: @S.Nick Всё добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам не нужна эта часть кода. Скомпилировали и забудьте про него.

Далее пишите свое приложение, в котором импортируете модуль созданный в дизайнере и скомпилированный `from main import Ui_Dialog`

Создаете класс куда закачиваете свой дизайн, примерно так:

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from main import Ui_Dialog


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        # тут ваша логика...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Все, запускайте свое приложение. Запускать приложение надо в CMD/терминале.

---

**Update**

Попробуйте кликать по кнопкам.

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from main  import Ui_Dialog


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.textEdit.setPlainText("Hello World")

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.pushButton_9.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.pushButton_10.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    def onClicked(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        self.textEdit.setPlainText(sender.text())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: NameError: name 'QDialog' is not defined

Comment: QtWidgets.QDialog() так надо здесь class Dialog(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):

Comment: Всё равно NameError: name 'QDialog' is not defined @Александр

Comment: Ой, это я не так сделал сейчас перепроверю, извините.

Comment: QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget @Александр

Comment: @BuldogMaster я подправил, пробуйте.

Comment: Скопируйте  как есть и запустите

Comment: @S.Nick Заработало спасибо большое!! Только ещё один вопрос. Где вы написали ```# тут ваша логика..``` можно делать функции(Я имею ввиду ```def name():``` ?)

Comment: @BuldogMaster я вам писал, опубликуйте в вопросе ваш файл `.ui` и я вам покажу, что такое логика.

Comment: @S.Nick Так я же в конце ссылку на яндекс диск добавил.

Comment: @BuldogMaster не надо никаких ссылок (она у меня не читается) - опубликуйте в вопросе.

Comment: @S.Nick Готово добавил

Comment: @S.Nick за вывод отвечает sender = self.sender?

Comment: @BuldogMaster нет. Читаем https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html и https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender

Comment: @S.Nick Хорошо, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то решением будет для вас ключ -x (pyuic5 -x test.ui -o test.py)

Comment: да, вы правильно поняли вопрос, но нужно учесть, что речь идет о `pyside2-uic`